# Downloading an Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm fairly new to programming in Android Studio and I wanted to download a project for streaming a radio station:

https://github.com/tjnicolaides/Radio-Station-Stream-App-for-Android

However, I don't know how to run it, because the run button was greyed out when I opened it.  When I clicked "Edit Configuration" and tried to add a configuration of the type "Application," it said there were no tasks specified.  How do I run this project?

Comment: that project is over 5 years old -- before Android Studio was around. You're better off creating a new project then merging the code from that project into it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you opened the project correctly.
Please try this: go to `File -> Open...` and select the most external build.gradle file (the one in the root folder).

Answer (score 0):

you must set your version of SDK compatible with that SDK project